# How can I use a custom tslint rule written in TypeScript with vscode-tslint without compiling to JS?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have a custom rule written for TSlint in TypeScript that I can run using `ts-node` in a script I'm using on my Linux VM:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ROOT_DIR=$(dirname $(dirname $0))
cd $ROOT_DIR
find "$ROOT_DIR/src" -name "*.ts" -o -name "*.tsx" | xargs $(yarn bin)/ts-node $(yarn bin)/tslint
```

This enables `tslint` to run the TS rule directly without compiling first, and it does work.

The problem is that `ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin` isn't picking up that rule even though it's explicitly enabled in the `tsconfig.json` rules. I am running VSCode on a separate machine with a Windows host, mounting the filesystem via Samba served from the Linux VM. Other rules in the file are being respected and shown for installed and built-in rules, like `no-console`, etc.

How can I get information about why the rule isn't being applied? Is there something I need to configure in the plugin to make this work?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-tslint-plugin/blob/master/src/runner/index.ts

Comment: I'm not quite sure what info I can glean from that file. Are you saying the runner needs to implement the parsing of the rule file in order to support TypeScript rules?

Comment: I'm saying vscode plugin might not behave the same as tslint CLI tool. To find out why, only way is to dive into its source code. [ln:287](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-tslint-plugin/blob/master/src/runner/index.ts#L287) is where it kicks spin the linter. Some logs around that line can reveal more info.

Comment: OK, thanks for those pointers, I'll dig in and see how that goes!

Comment: Looks like the plugin just let `tslint` instance [get configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-tslint-plugin/blob/master/src/runner/index.ts#L234), and  this is how `tslint` [load rules](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/4b3aa6ad84730e27fe2fe57595ba2e5b7d8214ef/src/ruleLoader.ts#L122)

Comment: To sum up, it's just node's `require`. And since the plugin loads `tslint` as a dependency, the node instance where that `tslint` app runs in is the same as where vscode plugin runs, which is a child process spinned up by vscode/electron.

Comment: So solution will be to find a way to teach that particular node process's `require` method to understand `.ts` files.

Comment: haven't tested, but guessing from source code, put `require('ts-node/register')` at the beginning of your custom rule `.ts` file could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by VScode/vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin and doesn't seem to be in their agenda.

[Here is a closed issue on their GitHub asking for this feature.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/313)

You can of course compile your rule to JS first, but it is not what you asked for.

Comment: That repository relates to the deprecated version of `tslint` for VSCode, so I might file a request to see if there's a way to support it in this version. Thanks!

Comment: The [official stance](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin/issues/105) is that this is out of scope for support in the new extension as well, so I guess that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think might be related to the problem.

- Let us name the rule file `noImportsRule.ts`. Rules are referenced in `tslint.json` with their kebab-cased identifier, so `"no-imports": true` would configure the rule.
- Core rules cannot be overwritten with a custom implementation.
- Custom rules can also take in options just like core rules (retrieved via `this.getOptions())`
- As of TSLint v5.7.0 you no longer need to compile your custom rules before using them. You need to tell node.js how to load .ts files for example by using ts-node:

**Important conventions:**

- Rule identifiers are always kebab-cased.
- Rule files are always camel-cased (`camelCasedRule.ts`).
- Rule files must contain the suffix `Rule`.
- The exported class must always be named Rule and extend from `Lint.Rules.AbstractRule`

for all [details](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/)

Comment: Thanks for that info, but the rule works just fine with the CLI, as explained above. The problem I have is that the VS Code tslint extension doesn't load the rule in `.ts` form without compiling to JS.

Comment: i think compiling to js is interesting with your webpack babel or lint configuration. You should say that i dont want to expose as js in your config. Can you share your configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The hack I develop goes like this:

1. assume your custom rules lives under `./rules`, the directory looks like:

```
rules/
  |- registerRule.js
  |- oneRule.ts
  |- twoRule.ts
```

2. `oneRule.ts` and `twoRule.ts` are actual rules written in typescript, but `registerRule.js` is a "spy". The purpose of this spy rule is just to get itself picked-up by `tslint` instance and inject the `ts-node/register` into the node runtime.

```
// registerRule.js

require('ts-node/register')

const Lint = require('tslint')

class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  apply(sourceFile) {
    return []
  }
}

module.exports.Rule = Rule
```

3. setup `tslint.json`

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": "./rules",
  "rules": {
    "register": true,
    "one": true,
    "two": true
  }
}
```

I've tested. This hack will teach the vscode tslint plugin to understand `.ts` custom rules.

Comment: I would like to avoid hacking in support for `ts-node`, since it could adversely affect the language server and cause all sorts of interop problems.

Comment: @KlemenSlavič IMO the it's under control. It only affect the behavior of `require` for any file with `.ts` ext, things other than that stay unaffected